# Python: numpy and minimize: set the minimum and/or maximum array

Tags: python, numpy, max, minimum

if I have a picture like
Result of the autocorrelation function:
and I need to find my first maximum as well as my first minimum

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 6, 1000)

sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

ACF = np.correlate(sig, sig, mode='full')
res_ACF = ACF[len(sig)-1:]
res_ACF /= np.max(res_ACF)


plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, sig, lw=0.5, label='signal originel')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(x, res_ACF, lw=3, label='ACF_with_np_correlate_in_full_mode')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ndarray.argmax` and `ndarray.argmin`

Answer (score 1):

2 simple for loops can do that

```
for i in range(1,len(res_ACF)-1):
    if res_ACF[i-1] > res_ACF[i] < res_ACF[i+1]:
        print('first minima: ', i, res_ACF[i])
        break

for i in range(1,len(res_ACF)-1):
    if res_ACF[i-1] < res_ACF[i] > res_ACF[i+1]:
        print('first maxima: ', i, res_ACF[i])
        break
```

yes, you can optimize it to use single for-loop.

Comment: In numpy, vectorization is much faster than a for loop, so you should try to avoid using for loop.

Comment: thank you for your answer, 
but you can see with this picture that if I use the loop for it gives me false results.

Comment: @yassinedhifaoui can't see the picture :|

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t know how to put the picture here please you can launch this program and see the result to chat.

plt.axvline(res_max,color='red')
plt.axvline(res_min,color='red')

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZsWj.png

You can see here this picture

Comment: @yassinedhifaoui `i` is the index for minima/maxima.
`x[i]` is x coordinate for minima/maxima. 
`res_ACF[i]` is y coordinate for minima/maxima.

I think you are plotting y value on x axis.

Comment: @Nawal I have the data,I work for this program to watch this first minimal and the first maximum.But with double dip autocorrelation it does not work.But in simple dip he give me this result.Can you do something for me?
Can't see the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVC3J.png
AND THIS FOR SIMPLE DIP : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrCWA.png

Comment: @yassinedhifaoui Can you share the code and data to reproduce ...

Answer (score 0):

`argmin`/`argmax` return the index of the min/max value:

```
plt.axvline(x[res_ACF.argmax()], c='r')
plt.axvline(x[res_ACF.argmin()], c='r')
```

[image]

Comment: I have the data,I work for this program to watch this first minimal and the first maximum.But with double dip autocorrelation it does not work.But in simple dip he give me this result.Can you do something for me? Can't see the picture: i.stack.imgur.com/FVC3J.png AND THIS FOR SIMPLE DIP : i.stack.imgur.com/NrCWA.png